# How do I add a click event to individual dynamically generated objects?

Tags: c#

This code I am writing right now generates a variable amount of independent objects. Can I give each of those objects the property that if it it clicked, that single object changes color?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using a button.

```
var button = new Button();
//set other properties...
button.Click += Button_Click; //the event already exists
```

Now cast the sender (the control that was clicked) and change the back color

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var theButton = (Button)sender;
    theButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```